# Grunt CDNify does not CNDify the files

Tags: angularjs, build, gruntjs, cdn, yeoman

I using Yeoman and trying to use grunt to build and optimize my dist.

I noticed that after `cdnify:dist` my index.html file is the same after the same and still referencing to local bower.

```html
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

this build process seem to pass Ok:

```
Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
```

Using AngularJS 1.2.6, CDNify 0.2.2.

My bower.json seem to be in line with the [guidelines](https://github.com/btford/grunt-google-cdn/blob/master/README.md)

Am I missing something? Is there other alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [reported issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/266) with CDNify. It seems google-cdn is hard-coding supported versions, which Angular 1.2.x is currently not.

[*Dan Smith* (AKA *X1011*)](https://github.com/X1011), worked around this by using [grunt-htmlrefs](https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-htmlrefs) to update script tags manually. You can see how he did it [in this commit](https://github.com/X1011/verge-mobile-bingo/compare/9beabadb09...caa9f1f4ba) of his *verge-mobile-bingo*.

Comment: Seems like it is still not totally worked out.  concatenation and minifying are still actions I would like performed with the vendor scripts were not located.  Dan Smith appeared to take those actions out.