# Unable to write "undefined" file during grunt:htmlrefs build

Tags: gruntjs

The setup looks good, but for somereason it can't see the index.html file?
What have I done wrong?  cdnify ran right before this and it worked no problem, actually everything except htmlrefs works just fine  (except cdnify won't work with angular1.2.12!)

**Grunt output**

```
Running "htmlrefs:dist" (htmlrefs) task
Warning: Unable to write "undefined" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to continue.
```

**Gruntfile**

```
    htmlrefs: {
        dist: {
            src: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'
        }
    }

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',  // For css files
    'concat',
    'preprocess:js',  // Remove DEBUG code from production builds
    'preprocess:html',  // Remove DEBUG code from production builds
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'htmlrefs',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Comment: Is the path correct of `'<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'` ? You can check using the `--verbose` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly define the dest:

htmlrefs: {
        dist: {
            src: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'
        }
    }

The [example I drew my setup from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661289/grunt-cdnify-does-not-cndify-the-files/21787263#21787263) did not do this, but after specifying it explicitly my build was fixed.